# How to create a SKU generator based on 2 conditions in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Im trying to create a SKU generator

I want to select model in A2, then just mark with checkboxes in the next 2 lists (colors and sizes) , and generate automatically what is needed for each one, its hard to explain but the
[demo sheet is here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZB_mgBqHLG9GiUx7UXVnMDkOuUBqfqB2itoeTwsgbrk/edit?usp=sharing)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a new sheet ("Erik Help") to your sample spreadsheet. The following formula produces the header and results for all selected SKUs:

`=ArrayFormula({"SKU List";FLATTEN(FLATTEN(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>"")&"-"&TRANSPOSE(FILTER(C2:C,D2:D=TRUE)))&TRANSPOSE(FILTER(F2:F,G2:G=TRUE)))})`

The header "SKU List" can be changed within the formula if you like.

`FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>"")&"-"` selects only non-null listings in Col A and adds a dash character. Each element of this shortlist is then concatenated (using the ampersand symbol) with a `TRANSPOSE`d `FILTER` of only those listings in Col C where Col D is `TRUE`.

This grid of results is `FLATTEN`ed into one column. Then this new list is again concatenated with a `TRANSPOSE`d `FILTER` of only those listings in Col F where Col G is `TRUE`.

Once again, this new virtual grid is finally `FLATTEN`ed into a single-column list.

Comment: Happy to help. And thanks for marking the post as "Best Answer." This helps the contributor community here be more efficient, because we can see at a glance which issues have been fully resolved; and it helps future site visitors quickly find relevant answers.